# SQL - select query / Remove records with duplicate values in desired columns

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

I have SQL table with about 15 columns but following columns are important:

```
Id, Area, Action, Timestamp.
```

Area represents entities of my app (user, document etc.) and Action represents what user did `(create, view, edit, cancel, etc...).` With select statement I get this data and it represents some kind of history (what user did on app). If I do few same actions on same area, only timestamp will distinguish them (if we don't consider timestamp, they are duplicates). How can I get rid of "duplicate" records considering values in desired columns (for example only area, action) and take only most recent one (by timestamp)? I tried some queries by using `DISTINCT` but couldn't achieve it.

EDIT: It is MSSQL.
My initial query is like (just few important columns, take into account that there are more columns):
[image]

There are some "duplicate" records if we consider just Area, Action columns. For example multiple records where area is `Notice` and action is `Details`. Final result should be last 5 records ordered by Timestamp (desc) and without duplicates according to (area, action) values.

Comment: Please show your query

Comment: Show sample data too. Raw and expected results.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I have edited my question. It is MS-SQL and I provided initial query with just selecting * from table.

Answer (score 0):

You can group them together and pick the max timestamp value

```
SELECT Id, Area, Action, MAX(timestamp) as max_ts
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Id, Area, Action
```

Comment: It would be ok if `Id, Area, Action, TimeStamp` were only columns, but as I wrote in edit, there are more columns in table. So for your solution, the rest of columns should be added to GROUP BY clause, otherwise it reports error. But if I add rest of them, it will return duplicates by `Area, Action` again.

Comment: This will work.  If the OP wants the rest of the data then they should build on this by using this as a sub-query and retrieving records from the original table that match the results from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below query will return the results you are after.  Using a sub-query you retrieve the latest timestamp for the Id / Area / Action, then join the subquery back to the original table to retrieve the rest of the data.

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM yourtable
    INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT Id, Area, Action, MAX(timestamp) as max_ts
                    FROM yourtable
                    GROUP BY Id, Area, Action)  maxtimestamp
        ON      yourtable.id = maxtimestamp.id
            AND yourtable.area = maxtimestamp.area
            AND yourtable.Action = maxtimestamp.action
            AND yourtable.timestamp = maxtimstamp.max_ts
```

With credit to SriniV's answer for the sub-query.

Comment: If I remove `Id` column from both query and subquery, it seems like it works. Now I should restrict result set to `TOP 5` by `TimeStamp` (DESC).

Comment: Yes, restricting the result set either in the sub-query or against the main query should get you the result you are after.

Comment: It worked, I restricted it in subquery because it is my initial resultset. Now, when I execute query alone, it returns correct result, descending by timeStamp. But when I put it into stored procedure (using transaction) it returns correct records but in ASCENDING order (inverted). Have you ever met with such issue?

Comment: Add an order by clause to your outer query, that will force the results into the order you want.  When you to the TOP 5 By logic in the sub-query it doesn't force the final results into the order by want.

Comment: Exactly like that. It couldn't come to my mind to put ORDER BY on outer query ...